# AllowEdit doesn't work properly in Dynamics AX

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

I have set Grid's and its fields AllowEdit properties to 'Yes', but anyway it reacts like readonly. What can be a reason of it?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set allowedit on the form data sources (data sources node of you form). 
Check if the AllowEdit property of the data source is set to "Yes".

Also check in code whether your data source of controls aren't set to allowEdit(false) programmatically. Right click the form and use the find... form to search for "allowedit".

An other property you should check is the "enabled" property on your controls.

Answer (score 0):

can you give us more info? For example what kind of form is it? In LisPages, you can't edit in grid. In List+Details, you can't edit in the list but in details on the right. Just to be sure it is not a UI/UX best practice inherited from the from template.

Regards,
Geoffrey

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I already solved it. The problem was in datasource which I set on Grid properties